# docx4j can't open template file on mac os x

Tags: java, macos, zip, docx4j

i have a problem using docx4j 2.8.1.
In VMWare Fusion windows xp i create an docx word file using MS office 2010, with plugin OpenDope. Add to the file 2 simple bindings and save this file as docx. Than i copy this file to resource/templates/test.docx file on my original mac, and in eclipse try to execute next code:

```
InputStream template = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/test.docx");
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(template);
```

and calling "load" method lead to exception below:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Error processing zip file (is it a zip file?)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:185)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:213)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:184)
at com.agiliumlabs.hr.server.ResumeConverter.getDocx(ResumeConverter.java:34)
at com.agiliumlabs.tests.TestResumeGenerate.main(TestResumeGenerate.java:22)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: oversubscribed dynamic bit lengths tree
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:147)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.getBytesFromInputStream(LoadFromZipNG.java:121)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:178)
... 6 more
```

Can any one give an advise for this situation? I use Mac OS 1.7.4, jdk 1.6.

Comment: Sounds like the docx file has become corrupted - maybe in the transfer from Windows XP to Mac?  Confirm you can open the file again in Word in Windows XP, then try opening it with something else in OSX: say LibreOffice/OpenOffice, or unzip.

Comment: yes, that was first what i trying to, and with success. It is open fine.
I can say more, if i open the same file like as:
    InputStream template = new FileInputStream("/Users/alex/tmp/test.docx");
it is load fine too. Problem appear only when trying to open file as:
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/test.docx")

Comment: any news on that? i have the exact same problem.